# xslt 3 : How to convert xml to pdf with xslt

Tags: pdf, xslt-3.0

I have an xml file and I want to create a pdf file from it using 'XSLT', the question is which processor should I work with (I know saxon.js, but it only processes XSLT into html or xml)
Does anyone know?

Comment: The usual tools in the Java world are Apache FOP plus Saxon (latest version to support XSLT 3 is Saxon 11, available in the open-source HE edition). You need to write XSLT to transform your XML to XSL-FO and feed that to the Apache FOP processor. Of course using SaxonJS's `xslt3` command line tool to transform your XML to XSL-FO will work as well, the chaining with Apache FOP then requires Shell or Node.js scripting to call Apache FOP via java.

Comment: Is it possible to convert from xslt to pdf/a3 as well?

Comment: Maybe you have an example of converting xml to PDF by XSLT?

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do is XML + XSLT -> HTML and then use a HTML to PDF generator such as Headless Chromium.